# Javascript Regular expression to get the Time from the string text

Tags: javascript, regex, timezone

I want to detect a string of text to get the time from the content of my page using javascript. Regular expression should be able to match all occurrences of the below strings.

- 10:00 PM CST
- 12/10/2014 05:00 AM IST
- 11-02-2015 23:00 CST
- 05/2/2015 10:00 PM EST
- 23rd Jan 2015 02:00 IST
- 04:00AM CST

I have tried with the following two regular expressions but they does not cover all the scenarios yet.

### Time Match

```
[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)
```

### Date Match

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|
(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|
(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|
(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|
[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|
[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|
[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|
(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

I have gotten too far into this using RegEx, but it matches some of the examples above just fine. Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: Have you tried momentjs? http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
/((?:(?:\d{1,2}(?:\/|-)){2}\d{4}\s+|\d{2}(?:rd|th|nd)\s+(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{4}\s+|)\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\s*(?:AM|PM))?\s+[IEC]ST)/g
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/jU9hJ8/2)